# Each of the girls in Mark's shop spent "their" or "her" money buying cakes

Tags: word-usage, possessives, personal-pronouns, singular-they, quantifiers

Can you please tell me if we  would use *their* or *her* as a possessive pronoun in this sentence?

- Each of the girls in Mark's shop spent *their* money buying cakes.
- Each of the girls in Mark's shop spent *her* money buying cakes.

Comment: Relevant recent Language Log post: [Schooled on singular "they"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=32244)

Comment: I bet either are used. 'Their' is used in 'Present day - English'.

Answer (score 0):

'Their' would be more colloquial - except that a sentence beginning 'each of the girls' is never going to be colloquial; so use 'her'.

Answer (score -2):

When one uses "each," one is intentionally singling out every individual member of the common group. To my mind, that fact screams for the use of singular pronouns.

Comment: But 'their' is used in certain situations as a singular pronoun, and there are many who endorse say 'The murderer left their gun in the garden'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth \ The use of "their" is an expedient to avoid the use of gender-specific pronouns. It has the unfortunate side effect of changing the number, as well. I am a partisan of using, in such instances, the pronoun "its." "Their," after all, has three singular forms, one of which is "its."

Comment: Your answer doesn't discuss the acceptability of using singular 'their' in this case and hence does not fully address the question. The article sumelic links to looks at the broadening of the usage, and the question of acceptability. Since it is not definitive, sumelic wisely sticks to a 'comment'. // I'd say that gender-neutral _its_ for a person is non-standard. *'A butcher must wash its hands'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth \ I'm not an adherent of the singular-their confession. I realize that the use of "its" whose antecedent is a person is unsettling to some, but the use of what has been a plural-number form to denote an individual unsettles me more. Rather than redefine (or augment) the meaning of "their," it would have been far better to augment the meaning of the gender of "its," especially since gender doesn't count for much in my beloved English tongue, anyway.

Comment: I notice that I have been awarded a couple of down-votes, undoubtedly with more to come. I would rather have had the approval of Mmes. Rawn and Clarke (middle-school English teachers) and of Mmes. Royer, Greaney and Crozier (high-school English teachers) than to have every up-vote ever cast here.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), '_singular they_ had emerged by the 14th century and is common in everyday spoken English, but its use has been the target of criticism since the late 19th century.' Both ACGEL and CGEL take the view that the usage is nowadays generally acceptable. I'd take the view of Professors Quirk, Huddleston etc over that of quite a few schoolteachers. And such authority is what ELU is looking for. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun) says elsewhere '...use of it can be dehumanizing, and thus inappropriate.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth \ So it boils down to a choice between referring to a person of unknown gender (1.).as though the person were unsexed, or else (2.) as though the person were afflicted with a multiple-personality disorder. Sounds good to me. You win: I think I shall take up French, if only I can master that growled "r."

Comment: The more fundamental choice is between doing what most other Anglophones choose to do, and being a maverick.

Comment: Doesn't the question turn on the word *each*?
Is it not obvious that *the girls in Mark's shop spent their money buying cakes* would be correct except for *each of*?
In this case it doesn’t seem to me to matter whether the girls combined their cash and spent the pool on communal cakes, or every girl spent her own money on cakes.
*Each of* the girls could take *their* only if, for instance, each girl agreed to spend the pool on cakes…
It seems wholly perverse anyone would have thought of down-voting Senex for posting something so obviously true, it’s almost axiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The vast majority of speakers, however, would only endorse _The murderer left their gun in the garden_ if the murderer’s gender is unknown. I find it very hard to believe that a considerable percentage of speakers would find the much more relevantly parallel _The girl left their purse on the table_ acceptable (except if referring to someone else’s purse).